# How to get String from HTTP response to form another request Netty 4.0.10

Tags: java, netty

I'm very new to Netty, and not very versed in Java, and I'm trying to make a client that connects and downloads a HLS stream from Wowza.
My goal is not to view the video but to be able to make multiple simultaneous connections for stress testing a HLS stream provided by a Wowza server.

I've been using the [`HttpSnoopClient`](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/netty-4.0.10.Final/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/snoop) example as a starting point, and the example client successfully connects and downloads the playlist content from the url provided as an argument (`wowza-server/stream-name/playlist.m3u8`). Now, i have to form a new connection/request using the original URI and replacing `playlist.m3u8` with a part of the received response that I'm parsing (something like `chunklistxxxx.m3u8`). After that i need to process that response that will give me links to video files, and form new consecutive connections/requests for downloading those files. After the downloads are finished the process is repeated for new chunks.

My question is: How can i get the processed `String` from `HttpSnoopClientHandler` back to the main class so i can form a new connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, you could define a member field in your `HttpSnoopClientHandler`:

```
class HttpSnoopClientHandler ... {
    final BlockingQueue<String> content = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    final StringBuilder contentBuffer = new StringBuilder(...);

    public void channelRead0(...) {
        // On every HttpContent:
        contentBuffer.append(...);

        // On LastHttpContent:
        content.add(contentBuffer.toString());
        contentBuffer.setLength(0);
    }
}
```

Then you can get the `content` from your `Main` class:

```
HttpSnoopClientHandler h = channel.pipeline().get(HttpSnoopClientHandler.class);
String content = h.content.poll(timeout, timeUnit);
```